# A word for sacrificing oneself for a higher cause?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a concise word for the act of sacrificing one's own life for the greater good? I know martyrdom, but that tends to imply suffering more than it does death.

Comment: "imply suffering more than it does death"? No way. **martyrdom** *noun* the suffering or death of a martyr. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/martyr

Comment: @Kris is right.  *Martyr* is exactly the right word.  The use of *martyr* in cases where the person is not actually put to death is simply a figurative usage.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was mistaken as to the usage of the word.

Comment: @Jim We don't normally speak of dead soldiers as 'martyrs' do we? 'Oxford Dictionaries gives the meaning of 'martyr' as 'a person who is killed for their religious or other beliefs'. I sense that is not exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @WS2 We do, we should. The dictionary lists more. Look for the contemporary meaning.

Comment: @Kris In the extensive OED entry on 'martyr', a search on 'soldier' and 'war' reveals neither. It is not apparently given as one of the meanings. No country memorialises its war dead more than Britain, as anyone who has ever watched the Remembrance Day services in Whitehall, around the country, and the wearing of poppies, will tell you. Having been born when bombs were still falling, and grown up in an era of bereavement, and having lost a grandfather in the First WW, and whilst I have heard every kind of honorific about 'duty', I have never heard fallen soldiers referred to as 'martyrs'.

Comment: @WS2 *Martyrs' Day is an annual day observed by nations to salute the martyrdom of soldiers who lost their lives defending the sovereignty of the nation.* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrs%27_Day

Comment: @Kris And look at the list of countries who observe so-called 'martyrs day'. There is not a single European or indeed western country among them. In the English language 'martyr' is not a word used for a 'fallen hero in war'.

Comment: @WS2- My observation is that OP rejected *martyr,* not because it did not refer to the "right" sort of people, but because it was thought to "*imply suffering more than death*"  I think we are just pointing out that *martyrdom* does actually *require* death in all non-figurative usage, and it is therefore applicable in that respect.  Whether it is applicable to any particular instance of death for a higher cause is a different matter, but OP seemed to be happy with it apart from the *suffering vs death* interpretation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is [self-sacrifice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-sacrifice) but it is not exactly a single world. Just suggesting it, in case it suits your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use the word **hero**.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use the word **'altruism' or 'altruistic suicide'**. The term 'altruism' was first used by Emile Durkheim to describe a Suicide committed for the benefit of others or for the community: this would include self-sacrifice for military objectives in wartime. Altruistic suicides reflect a courageous indifference to the loss of one's life. Altruistic behaviour is found in many other species of animals too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a phrase: **[supreme sacrifice](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=supreme%20sacrifice)**

> the sacrifice of one's own life, esp. to save the life of another.